# Proof that any $z \in \mathbb{C}$ can be written as $re^{i \theta}$

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove that for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$, we can write $z = re^{ i \theta}$ where $r = |z|$ and $\theta$ is the polar angle. I do not understand the solution that I am looking at, and was hoping someone could look over my understanding of the argument.

The first step is to write: 
\begin{align*}
re^{i \theta} & = |z|e^{ i \theta} & & \text{given $r = |z|$} \\
& = |z|\left(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta\right) & & \text{Euler's identity} \\
& = |z| \cos \theta + (|z| \sin \theta) i  
\end{align*}
So far I haven't any issue with anything in this solution. The next step, however, does not make sense to me. The assertion is that "by trigonometry, we have" 
$$z = |z|\cos \theta + (|z| \sin \theta)i.$$
And equality is obvious from this point by equating this with $re^{i \theta}$ above. I do not understand how to derive this fact using trigonometry. The best I can do with trigonometry is, for some arbitrary point in the complex plane with radius $r$ and polar angle $\theta$, draw a right triangle with sides $x = r \cos \theta$, $y = r \sin \theta$, and $r = x^2 + y^2$.

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you left out $i$ in the title

Comment: I did. Sorry about that, and thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

You know that any complex number $z$ is written as
$$
z=a+bi,\quad a,b\in\mathbb R.
$$
You have to prove that this can be always written  in the form:
$$ 
z=r e^{i\theta}=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta).
$$
So, consider $z=a+bi$. If $z=0$, then you have $z=0\cdot e^{i\theta}$ for any $\theta$ and you have finished. If $z\neq 0$, define
$$
r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}>0
$$
and write
$$
z=a+ib=r\left(\frac
{a}{r}+\frac
{b}{r}\right).
$$
Then $ \frac
{a}{r}\in [-1,1]$ and you can define
$$
\theta=\pm\arccos(a/r)\Rightarrow a/r=\cos\theta.
$$
Then you prove that, choosing the appropriate sign, $\sin\theta=b/r. $ Indeed
$$
\left(\frac{a}{r}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{r}\right)^2=1\Rightarrow \frac{b}{r}=\pm\sqrt{1-(a/r)^2}=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}
$$

Comment: I appreciate the thorough answer, though I was hoping someone could take a look at that line of the proof that I struggled with.

Comment: Well, I suppose that "using trigonometry" in this context amounts essentially to use the identity $ \cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$, which is nedeed also in my answer.